cannot connect to the docker deaemon at unix://var/rundocker.sock. is the docker daemon run?
I’m using OP-TEE on qemu v8 and am trying to run docker on buildroot, but I’m getting the following error:
cannot connect to the docker deaemon at unix://var/rundocker.sock. is the docker daemon run?

I'm adding following packages:
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSECCOMP_ARCH_SUPPORTS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBSECCOMP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_CA_CERTIFICATES=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_CLI=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_COMPOSE=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_DOCKER_ENGINE=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_CONTAINERD=y 
BR2_PACKAGE_RUNC=y


I am not sure what op-tee or qemu has to do with docker, but there seems to be a slash missing between run and docker.sock. What Buildroot version are you using and what is your configuration exactly? Did you modify the DOCKER_HOST environment variable?

Actually I have build OP-TEE on Qemu and I'm running my docker compose on buildroot which is the OP-TEE's normal world. To what I should change DOCKER_HOST?

but OP-TEE is presumably unrelated to all of this? Please explain more details of your Buildroot setup, E.G. what Buildroot version, what configuration, what commands do you run on the emulated system?
